# How to edit user permissions only for selected fields on Opencart?

Tags: php, opencart

I've set up a **non-admin** user group on OC dashboard. Now I need to give permission for that user group to view and update all products but **not to update Model and Quantity** (only to view model and quantity). How could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done by default in OpenCart, you will need to look for an answer on the forums: https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=134562

Or in the extension store: https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension&filter_search=permissions

Answer (score 0):

Finally this is how I solved:

Added the following lines to admin/controller/catalog/product.php

```
$this->load->model('user/user_group');
$data['user_groups_id'] = $this->user->getGroupId();
```

Then updated admin/view/template/catalog/product_form.twig

```
{% if user_groups_id == 11 %}
    <input type="text" name="sku" value="{{ sku }}" placeholder="{{ entry_sku }}" 
      id="input-sku" class="form-control" disabled/>
{% else %}
    <input type="text" name="sku" value="{{ sku }}" placeholder="{{ entry_sku }}" 
      id="input-sku" class="form-control" />
{% endif %}
```